# Интересный и простой вопрос hover + z-index)

Tags: javascript, hover, z-index

Вопрос простой, но интересный. Подскажите, как быть, если не срабатывает hover на объекте у которого z-index. Как можно на него навестись при ховере и индексе одновременно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно поверх него повесить другой прозрачный блок такого же размера, и привязать hover к нему. `.transparent:hover + .instruction-todolist { ... }`. Не очень понятно, «нафига», если можно просто убрать отрицательный z-index)

Comment: хм, точно) Спасибо! )

Comment: Хотя если повесить прозрачный, то ховер тоже будет срабатывать на нем, а нужен же нижний элемент.

Comment: Уберите скриншоты и добавьте код. Вы уверены что проблема в z-index?

Answer (score 0):

z-index: -1; означает, что ваш элемент идет в самый нижний слой, из-за которого до него нельзя будет достучаться курсором, поэтому вам надо убрать z-index, чтобы он вернулся в доступный слой и реагировал на поведения курсора